# ORACLE SQL: Create new row on the basis of date range

Tags: sql, oracle, date

For example, I am having a table name test_cross_months and the data is as below :

| id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 44 | 2020-01-04 | 2020-01-04 |
| 44 | 2020-01-30 | 2020-02-10 |
| 44 | 2020-02-27 | 2020-03-03 |

Expected result:

| id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 44 | 2020-01-04 | 2020-01-04 |
| 44 | 2020-01-30 | 2020-01-31 |
| 44 | 2020-02-01 | 2020-02-10 |
| 44 | 2020-02-27 | 2020-02-29 |
| 44 | 2020-03-01 | 2020-03-03 |

So for
|44|2020-01-30  |2020-02-10|
there should be two rows that are from 30-Jan-2020 to 31-Jan-2020 and 1-Feb-2020 to 10-Feb-2020

I tried by comparing the end date with the last day for the start_date but facing issues as a new row is not getting created for the end_date range.

Could any please suggest a solution?

Comment: What if `44 2020-02-27 2020-04-03` ?

Comment: then it will be
2020-02-27 2020-02-29
2020-03-01     2020-03-31
2020-04-01     2020-04-03

Comment: Thanks a lot for an answer I will try the below SQL as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive query (which will work regardless of how many months your ranges span):

```sql
WITH months ( id, start_date, end_date, final_date ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         start_date,
         LEAST( LAST_DAY( start_date ), end_date ),
         end_date
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         end_date + INTERVAL '1' DAY,
         LEAST( ADD_MONTHS( end_date, 1 ), final_date ),
         final_date
  FROM   months
  WHERE  end_date < final_date
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY final_date SET dt_order
SELECT id,
       start_date,
       end_date
FROM   months;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, start_date, end_date) AS
SELECT 44, DATE '2020-01-04', DATE '2020-01-04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 44, DATE '2020-01-30', DATE '2020-02-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 44, DATE '2020-02-27', DATE '2020-03-03' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | START_DATE | END_DATE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 44 | 2020-01-04 00:00:00 | 2020-01-04 00:00:00 |
> | 44 | 2020-01-30 00:00:00 | 2020-01-31 00:00:00 |
> | 44 | 2020-02-01 00:00:00 | 2020-02-10 00:00:00 |
> | 44 | 2020-02-27 00:00:00 | 2020-02-29 00:00:00 |
> | 44 | 2020-03-01 00:00:00 | 2020-03-03 00:00:00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1fd390320b936c8d41406a2e24c7a530)*

Answer (score 0):

Using a table of numbers and date arithmetic

```
-- example of table of numbers
with nmbrs(n) as(
   select 0 from dual union all
   select 1 from dual union all
   select 2 from dual 
)
select t.id, 
   case when n=0 then t.start_date else trunc(t.start_date, 'MM') + NUMTOYMINTERVAL(n, 'MONTH') end s,
   case when n=MONTHS_BETWEEN(last_day(t.end_date), last_day(t.start_date)) then t.end_date 
       else last_day(t.start_date + NUMTOYMINTERVAL(n, 'MONTH')) end e
from test_cross_months t
join nmbrs on nmbrs.n <= MONTHS_BETWEEN(last_day(t.end_date), last_day(t.start_date))
order by t.id, s
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=eaee15c12d50b4e68778e2bf3133fa07)

Comment: What happens if the range crosses 3 months? Or 50 months? Or 900 months? You have a static range of numbers and this approach requires you to always know the maximum size of the date range that you will encounter otherwise the query will not return sufficient rows.

Comment: From a business point of view, months will not cross 4 to 5 months. Max date range will be 1 year but this also end user will not do it I think. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @MT0, this is just an example table of numbers. One may have an  instantiated table of millions rows in the DB or generate it on the fly according to input or just have application-reasonable fixed set of numbers in the query as in the example.